# Updating Omniture Variables on html events

Tags: javascript, jquery, adobe-analytics

I'm trying to update Omniture variables so that they instantly show up when the debugger is called.\

For example I'd like prop12 to be set to "ggg" when a button on page is clicked.

```
 $('#button').click(function(){
      gs.prop12 = "ggg";
 });
```

I have the SiteCatalyst.js file and there is no s but a gs object that contains all the variables, props ect.

But if I change or set the value, those changes don't show up in the debugger.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not enough info. Do you mean Adobe Digital Pulse? js console? some other sniffer? what browser? what "debugger" are you using? Be more specific about what you are wanting to happen and where.

Comment: How is that not enough info? I would like to update Omniture variables on a page using Javascript. There is a debugger Adobe provides which is a script that creates a popup window that shows all your present props, evars, events etc. I would like to update those variables using javascript based on page interaction. -_-

Comment: I gave you examples of why it's not enough info. That's like asking how to make your "browser" do xyz and get upset when I ask you *which* browser you are using. "Debugger" is generic. Lots of addons, built-in browser tools, and standalone programs "debug." So you have clarified that you are using Adobe's DigitalPulse debugger.  DigitalPulse only shows you requests that have already been sent to Adobe. It's not a "live" debugger that shows current variable states.

Comment: Here is the script that I run to bring up the debugger   javascript:void(window.open("","dp_debugger","width=600,height=600,location=0,menubar=0,status=1,toolbar=0,resizable=1,scrollbars=1").document.write("<script language='JavaScript' id=dbg src='https://www.adobetag.com/d1/digitalpulsedebugger/live/DPD.js'></"+"script>"));

Comment: Yes, that is adobe's DigitalPulse debugger. As mentioned, it only shows a listing of requests that have already been sent to Adobe on the page. It does not show you a real-time change in variable values or anything.

Comment: So let me rephrase my question. Is there a way to make variable changes and send the request to Adobe via javascript? Ajax call perhaps so that it shows up in DigitalPulse immediately after making the changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your latest comment:

> So let me rephrase my question. Is there a way to make variable
>   changes and send the request to Adobe via javascript? Ajax call
>   perhaps so that it shows up in DigitalPulse immediately after making
>   the changes?

Basically the way it works is you set variables and then make an `s.t()` or `s.tl()` call (or in your case, using `gs` namespace), which are the "triggers" that send all your set variables to Adobe.  So, yes. You can set variables to new values and then use one of the "triggers" to trigger another request to Adobe. However, not that this doesn't really *replace* previous values - it sends *new* values.

So for example if you set `prop12` to "foo" and make a request, and then set `prop12` to "bar" and make another request, you will see both "foo" and "bar" as separate entries in your reports. Also, once you make a `s.tl()` or `s.t()` call, you can refresh DigitalPulse and it will show a *new* entry, for the *new* request made to Adobe. Again, this doesn't *replace* the previous request - it submits an additional request, where data is aggregated in Adobe.

Now, there is an exception for some of the variables. For example, eVars (e.g. `eVar1`) can be set within the Adobe Analytics interface to have the value overwritten with a new value for the duration of its scope (expiration time). So for example if you configure `eVar1` to expire on visit and allocate it as most recent, then for the duration of the visit, the last value is what is shown for most metrics.  However, one metric "instances" will still show *all* values sent.

So back to your example code.  If you want to send a new value to Adobe after page load, on click of `#button`, you'd do for example this:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
      gs.linkTrackVars = "prop12";
      gs.prop12 = "ggg";
      gs.tl(true,"o","button click");
});
```

Couple of notes here:

- For click tracking (`tl()` calls) you must "register" the events and variables you want to include in the request. Since you are wanting to set `prop12`, you must specify it in `linkTrackVars`. If you were to also want to pop an event, you'd also make use of `linkTrackEvents`.
- `tl()` is used to make a "click" request to Adobe. A "click" request will record data but not count it as a page view ( `t()` calls are made for page views, which is why it is in the base on-page coding when a page is loaded).

In general, Adobe Analytics is a complex, enterprise level Analytics solution. I suggest you at least become intimate with [the documentation](http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/sc/implement/index.html) about how it works in general, and if you can afford it, I recommend signing up for one or more of their training/certification courses.

Comment: I voted you up for the typing effort and link to the documentation but that didn't work.

Comment: @Proximo well that's good Adobe Analytics syntax, so there must be an issue with your code elsewhere. Maybe the selector isn't right, etc..

Comment: Crayon, thanks.. best answer I've had on Stack Overflow